# Use iPhone clock to trigger events within app

Tags: iphone, xcode, clock

I'm creating an app in which I want to have a new set of text called from a .txt at the beginning of every day, at the moment I have it so that the set of files can be browsed through by the click of a button but this is too primitive for the purpose of the app.

Any help or suggestions on how to access and use the iPhone's clock would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will give you the current time from the iPhone clock

```
[NSDate date]
```

When the app opens, you can load up the text file, and store the date it was last loaded using NSUserDefaults (which is a simple store that persists over instantiations of the app)

Next time the app opens, retrieve the last date the file was loaded from NSUserDefaults and compare to the current date - if its more than 24 hours then reload (or whatever the logic is you require).

i.e.

when you load the text file

```
// Set the current date in NSUserDefaults
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nowDate forKey:@"LastLoaded"];
```

and on relaunch of the app

```
// Get the current date from NSUserDefaults
NSDate *lastLoaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastLoaded"];


NSDate *checkDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-24*60*60];
if ([lastLoaded compare:checkDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // reload file
}
```

note the above code is only off top of my head as an illustration - syntax and date creation comparison logic may be flawed.

Comment: Could you then use that to call a function? Or rather when the app is opened check how long it has been since it last was and whether it needs to update?

Comment: added a bit of an example as well